# Installing Tor for anonymous browsing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, tor

How to install Tor with just Tor browser on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa?

Comment: `sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/torbrowser-launcher) assuming you've enabled 'universe' repository (enabled by default for flavors, manually enabled for Ubuntu; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)  If that's not what you're asking, it's unclear sorry.

Comment: Thanks, however I installed it directly be downloading the .tar archive and setting it up in /opt, the traditional way. Is that okay?